# is it possible that an auto increment field duplicates?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table which has several field including:

1. contact_id
2. phone
3. phone_id

`contact_id` and `phone` are primary keys and `phone_id` is an auto increment field. I want to use it to recognize a certain entry. So I want to know that is it possible to duplicate that non primary field when I'm entering data.

Comment: If you run `SET IDENTITY_INSERT yourTable ON`, you can. Otherwise, you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is no constraint, some unique index, you can duplicate values in that column, because 1) you can turn identity_insert on, 2) you can reseed increments.

Here is a proof:

```
CREATE TABLE #test(id INT IDENTITY(1, 1))

INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test ON

INSERT INTO #test(id) VALUES(1)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #test OFF

INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES

DBCC CHECKIDENT ('#test', RESEED, 1);

INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES
INSERT INTO #test DEFAULT VALUES

SELECT * FROM #test

DROP TABLE #test
```

Output:

```
id
1
2
3
1
4
5
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is **Yes, it's possible.**
SQL Server does not force a unique constraint on identity columns, meaning that the can have duplicated values, however, Sql server will not generate duplicate values itself in an identity column.

Identity columns in sql server are populated by the sql server itself when you insert a row to the table.

However, you can specify a value to them by using [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx) before the insert statement.

There are a couple of things that you should be aware of:

1. Setting identity_insert on is per table. you can only set it for one table at the time.
2. Until you set the identity_insert back off, any insert statement to that table will have to specify a value for the identity column.
3. you can't use `set identity insert on` for more then one table on a single session. therefor after you've done inserting records to the table you must set the identity_insert back off on that table.